# Divisibility question while enumerating endomorphisms: PART 2

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

From *endomorphisms of rank 1* of the full transformation semigroup $[n]^{[n]}$ or *idempotents* in $[n]^{[n]}$, we have
$$c_n:=\sum_{m=1}^n\binom{n}mm^{n-m}.$$
Denote the $2$-adic valuation of $x$ by $\nu_2(x)$.

> **QUESTION.** Is it true that $\nu_2(c_n)=\nu_2(n-1)$, for $n\geq2$?

Comment: This is sequence 248 in the OEIS (https://oeis.org/A000248),
which gives some further information including the exponential generating 
function $\exp(x \exp(x))$ and some references and further interpretations.
Possibly one of those might lead to a proof.  For what it's worth 
$c_2 = 3$ seems to be the only multiple of $3$, and I don't see a pattern in 
the valuation at $5$ and $7$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: thanks for the references which I was aware of. I agree with your mod 3 comments. I also think that no such behavior occurs for other primes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true. The idea is to get $n-1$ out of the sum as a multiple.

We have $$c_n=1+\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}m{n\choose m}m^{n-1-m}=1+\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}n{n-1\choose m-1}m^{n-1-m}$$
We see that if $n$ is even, then $c_n$ is odd.

Now let $n>1$ be odd. Then proceed this way:$$c_n=1+n\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}{n-1\choose m-1}+n\sum_{m=2}^{n-2}{n-1\choose m-1}(m^{n-1-m}-1)\\=1+n(2^{n-1}-1)+n(n-1)\sum_{m=2}^{n-2}{n-2\choose m-2}\cdot \frac{m^{n-1-m}-1}{m-1}\\=:1+n(2^{n-1}-1)+n(n-1)A.$$
Modulo 2 we have $$\frac{m^{n-1-m}-1}{m-1}=1+m+\ldots+m^{n-m-2}\equiv 1+m(n-m-2)\equiv 1,$$
so
$$
A\equiv \sum_{m=2}^{n-2} {n-2\choose m-2}=2^{n-2}-1-(n-2)\equiv 0\pmod 2.
$$
Then $c_n=(1-n)+(n2^{n-1})+n(n-1)A$, and $1-n$ has 2-adic valuation strictly smaller than two other summands, thus $\nu_2(c_n)=\nu_2(1-n)$.